# Think of vs. figure out vs. work out

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Are the following examples all acceptable? If so, do they mean the same thing? Any nuances related to aspects?

> I've got to **think of** a way to earn more money.
>
> I've got to **figure out** a way to earn more money.
>
> I've got to **work out** a way to earn more money.

Comment: what's your take on these sentences? What you think about each of them?

Comment: I would think they are the same except that **think of** has an imperfective aspect while the other two have perfective aspects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meanings are very similar. The only difference, to my mind, involves the effort involved.

You can **think of something** out of the clear blue sky, without even trying. If you **figure something out,** you have set yourself a problem, or been set a problem, and solved it; this implies more effort. To **work something out** also implies an effort, and probably a more prolonged one; you can figure something out quickly, but it usually takes time to work something out.

For most practical purposes, though, they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I agree with this.  And "Work out" can be broader in meaning, and can include actions needed to accomplish the goal.